Conda install non-python library from github
I want to install QMCPack into my conda environment. This is not a python library so I can't do pip install.
How does one install a non-python package into a conda environment from github?

If it's not a Python package, then it won't be part of your environment.  Just install it globally.

Depends on what you need it for, and the OS you're on, but your best starting bet is to read the installation documentation
I don't think you can install it directly into conda though, but if it's installed globally (as mentioned by Tim Roberts), it should suffice
Here's a quick run-down of what you can do on the most common systems:

Linux: apt or yum
MacOS: Macports or Homebrew
Windows: WSL and Bash, wget, choco

